# NGINX HTTPS Proxy Not Working With Azure AD Redirect Uri

Tags: asp.net, azure, nginx, blazor, nginx-reverse-proxy

I recently developed a Blazor Server application that requires users to login through my Azure AD in order to access the app. The project uses .NET 7 and is published through a Docker container. I can login to my app with Azure AD perfectly fine while developing in Visual Studio with HTTPS.

In the past, I have simply hosted my Blazor projects as Docker containers, using NGINX as a reverse proxy. My NGINX configuration uses the following setup to point to any of my containers and force HTTPS (this container is exposed at 192.168.1.11:8081):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate     /https/tags/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /https/tags/server.key;

  # Configure the SignalR Endpoint
  location / {
    # App server url
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.11:8081;

    # Configuration for WebSockets
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    # Configuration for LongPolling or if your KeepAliveInterval is longer than 60 seconds
    proxy_read_timeout 100s;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Along with the default conf for HTTPS redirection:

```
    # Default
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      server_name _;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
```

However, with this setup I cannot authenticate into my Azure AD. It appears that the request is still being made from HTTP protocol: `AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://www.example.com/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application`. I am simply wanting this HTTP request to my app registration to be HTTPS instead.

I have tried many different approaches with my nginx config, but these current settings are the only way I can successfully reach the container. I have also tried adding ForwardedHeaders to my project's Program.cs as referenced here: [stackoverflow.com/azure-ad-nginx-reverse-proxy-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341461/net-core-2-0-azure-active-directory-nginx-reverse-proxy-https) but it does not fix the issue. I am not sure what approach to try next, as the other guides I have found so far are very outdated. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and after some searching found that my problem was with two issues. The first was changing the forwarded headers options.

Originally I had the following in my program.cs file.

```
  app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
  {
      ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
  });
```

I removed the ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor option as shown below, which made the redirectUri back to my site using the correct scheme, https. This was suggested on [this answer comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51486808/15944288)

```
  app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
  {
      ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
  });
```

Once that was resolved, I was receiving a 502 bad gateway error from nginx. The error logs were showing that it was actually an issue with the header size

```
2023/08/11 19:47:54 [error] 24#24: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

Some research on that led me to find some information on proxy buffer size for nginx. Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75611732/15944288) as inspiration, I added the below lines to my nginx conf file and I was up and working! A little documentation on that--[nginx proxy buffer size](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size)

```
   proxy_buffer_size        16k;
   proxy_buffers            8 16k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size  16k;
```

I hope this can help you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to put https including

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

in nginx.conf. I think you could try.